401 Response From TPR FMCSA
I am a training provider and I am trying to submit my drivers data for Online courses to TPR registry.
You can visit https://tpr.fmcsa.dot.gov/ to know more.
I am using their training Provider developer ToolKit and a sample data to send it to their API as per their documentation which is also attached in Toolkit.
Now I'm facing issue with my code.
The process is as follows.
1: They provide me a test location ID
2: Test Issuer Credential(iss)
3: A certificate from which I get Private key to sign my JWT token with
All of them are inside developer toolkit
What I need to do
1: Use them to generate a payload with iss
2: nbf: (Not Before) – must be the current time or later with a 5 minute skew for clocks
out of sync. The value must be provided as a Unix timestamp
3: exp: (Expiration) – must be no greater than 20 minutes after the “nbf” value and must
not be in the past, plus a 5 minute skew for clocks out of sync. The value must be
provided as a Unix timestamp
Then finally they have provided a test pfx file that I use to fetch the private key, Sign my JWT and encode with RS256 algo.
This is my endpoint: https://tpr.fmcsa.dot.gov/api/Training/Add
If I generate the JWT, send my sample Data using POSTMAN, it returns 201 correctly.
But from my PHP code, I get 401 http code and no errors.
Postman Request:
PHP CODE:
                $res = array();
        $pfxFile = 'Provider.pfx'; // test
        $pfxPassword = 'password'; // test 
        $pfxContents = file_get_contents($pfxFile);
        openssl_pkcs12_read($pfxContents, $cert_info, $pfxPassword);
        $private_key = $cert_info['pkey'];
        $issuer = 'acf62c64-db18-4285-9cab-f5f4a86d94bf'; //Test
        $locationId = '7d4b45a3-33f0-11eb-a244-00059a3c7a00'; //Test
        $current_time = time();
        // print_r($current_time);die;
        $nbf = $current_time;
        $exp = $current_time + 1200;
        $payload = [
            "nbf" => $nbf,
            "exp" => $nbf,
            "iss" => $issuer,
            // "sub" => $subject
        ];
        $jwt = JWT::encode($payload, $private_key, 'RS256');
        $url = 'https://tpr.fmcsa.dot.gov/api/Training/Add';
        $headers = array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer '. $jwt
        );

        $data = array(
            'Number' => 'S1278908',
            'State' => 'US-MA',
            'FirstName' => 'John',
            'LastName' => 'Smith',
            'DateOfBirth' => '1997-04-19',
            'ClassEndorsementCode' => 'A',
            'ApplicationType' => 'New',
            'ProviderLocationId' => '7d4b45a3-33f0-11eb-a244-00059a3c7a00',
            'TrainingElements' => array(
                array(
                    'TrainingType' => 'Theory',
                    'CompletionDate' => '2022-03-04',
                    'TrainingMethod' => 'InPerson',
                    'Score' => 95,
                    'InternalId' => 'TPREC-123456'
                )
            )
        );

        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
        $curlResponse = curl_exec($ch);
        $error = curl_error($ch);
        $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        
        curl_close($ch);

        if ($error) {
            $res['error'] = $error;
        }

        $res['response'] = $curlResponse;
        $res['status'] = $http_code;
        return $this->withJson($response, $res);


Response From CODE:


Check out how you specified the headers. One is a string, the other one is a key and string

You're absolutely right my friend. Thank you so much idk how on earth I missed that.
Also just found out from postman, I could've converted my curl request to any Code.
Thank you So much Evert.
